# Zoom Into the Area Cursor Points

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

Referring to this [CodePen demo here](https://codepen.io/maximus-su/pen/KKxPyaP?editors=1010), I created this zoom-in and zoom-out function which works fine.

May I ask the code to zoom in and out of the area which my cursor points using the mouse scroll?

For example, if my cursor is moved to the green area in my picture and when I scroll the mouse, it will zoom into and out of a specific area? Any help will be very much appreciated :)

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('mainsvg');
var gnode = document.getElementById('gnode');
var zoomPercentage = 0.25;
var MAXIMUM_ZOOM_HEIGHT = 1400;
var baseBox = {};
var level = 0;
var widthRatio, heightRatio;
var clientheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var clientwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

function setup() {
  var
    baseX,
    baseY,
    baseWidth,
    baseHeight,
    percentageDifference,
    heightDifference;

  svg.setAttribute('height', clientheight);
  svg.setAttribute('width', clientwidth);

  var boundry = document.getElementById('boundry');
  boundry.setAttribute('height', clientheight - 1);
  boundry.setAttribute('width', clientwidth - 1);

  var centernode = document.getElementById('centernode');
  centernode.setAttribute('cy', clientheight / 2);
  centernode.setAttribute('cx', clientwidth / 2);

  if (svg.height.baseVal.value >= MAXIMUM_ZOOM_HEIGHT)
    baseHeight = MAXIMUM_ZOOM_HEIGHT;
  else
    baseHeight = Math.round(gnode.getBBox().height) + 60;

  baseY = (svg.height.baseVal.value - baseHeight) / 2;
  percentageDifference = baseHeight / svg.height.baseVal.value;
  baseWidth = percentageDifference * svg.width.baseVal.value;
  baseX = (svg.width.baseVal.value - baseWidth) / 2;


  baseBox.x = baseX;
  baseBox.y = baseY;
  baseBox.width = baseWidth;
  baseBox.height = baseHeight;
  level = 0;

  heightDifference = MAXIMUM_ZOOM_HEIGHT - baseHeight;
  zoomPercentage = (heightDifference / 10) / heightDifference;

  setViewBox(baseBox);
}

function setViewBox(viewBox) {
  svg.viewBox.baseVal.x = Math.round(viewBox.x);
  svg.viewBox.baseVal.y = Math.round(viewBox.y);
  svg.viewBox.baseVal.width = Math.round(viewBox.width);
  svg.viewBox.baseVal.height = Math.round(viewBox.height);
  setRatios();
}

function setRatios() {
  widthRatio = svg.viewBox.baseVal.width / svg.width.baseVal.value;
  heightRatio = svg.viewBox.baseVal.height / svg.height.baseVal.value;
}

function calculateViewBox(level) {

  var
    height = baseBox.height - (zoomPercentage * level * baseBox.height),
    y = baseBox.y + (baseBox.height - height) / 2,
    width = baseBox.width - (zoomPercentage * level * baseBox.width),
    x = baseBox.x + (baseBox.width - width) / 2,
    viewBox = {
      x: x,
      y: y,
      width: width,
      height: height
    }
  return viewBox;
}

function zoomin() {
  level++;
  if (level > 5)
    level = 5;
  var
    x,
    y,
    paperViewBox = svg.viewBox.baseVal,
    previousViewBox = calculateViewBox(level - 1),
    newViewBox = calculateViewBox(level);
  //callback = this.afterZoom;

  if (Math.round(paperViewBox.x) > Math.round(newViewBox.x))
    /**
     * is panned left
     */
    x = paperViewBox.x - (previousViewBox.width - newViewBox.width) / 2;
  else if (Math.round(paperViewBox.x) < Math.round(previousViewBox.x) - (Math.round(newViewBox.x) - Math.round(previousViewBox.x)))
    /**
     * is panned right
     */
    x = paperViewBox.x + (previousViewBox.width - newViewBox.width) + (previousViewBox.width - newViewBox.width) / 2;
  else
    x = newViewBox.x;

  if (Math.round(paperViewBox.y) > Math.round(newViewBox.y))
    /**
     * is panned up
     */
    y = paperViewBox.y - (previousViewBox.height - newViewBox.height) / 2;
  else if (Math.round(paperViewBox.y) < Math.round(previousViewBox.y) - (Math.round(newViewBox.y) - Math.round(previousViewBox.y)))
    /**
     * is panned down
     */
    y = paperViewBox.y + (previousViewBox.height - newViewBox.height) + (previousViewBox.height - newViewBox.height) / 2;
  else
    y = newViewBox.y;


  var data = {
    viewBox: {
      x: x,
      y: y,
      width: newViewBox.width,
      height: newViewBox.height
    }
  }

  SetZoomViewBox(data);
}

function SetZoomViewBox(data) {
  var viewBox = data.viewBox;

  svg.viewBox.baseVal.x = Math.round(viewBox.x);
  svg.viewBox.baseVal.y = Math.round(viewBox.y);
  svg.viewBox.baseVal.width = Math.round(viewBox.width);
  svg.viewBox.baseVal.height = Math.round(viewBox.height);
  setRatios();

}

function zoomout() {
  level--;
  if (level < 0)
    level = 0;
  var
    x,
    y,
    paperViewBox = svg.viewBox.baseVal,
    previousViewBox = calculateViewBox(level + 1),
    newViewBox = calculateViewBox(level);

  if (Math.round(paperViewBox.x) > Math.round(previousViewBox.x) + (Math.round(previousViewBox.x) - Math.round(newViewBox.x)))
    /**
     * is panned left
     */
    x = paperViewBox.x - (newViewBox.width - previousViewBox.width);
  else if (Math.round(paperViewBox.x) < Math.round(previousViewBox.x))
    /**
     * is panned right
     */
    x = paperViewBox.x;
  else
    x = newViewBox.x;

  if (Math.round(paperViewBox.y) > Math.round(previousViewBox.y) + (Math.round(previousViewBox.y) - Math.round(newViewBox.y)))
    /**
     * is panned up
     */
    y = paperViewBox.y - (newViewBox.height - previousViewBox.height);
  else if (Math.round(paperViewBox.y) < Math.round(previousViewBox.y))
    /**
     * is panned down
     */
    y = paperViewBox.y;
  else
    y = newViewBox.y;


  var data = {
    viewBox: {
      x: x,
      y: y,
      width: newViewBox.width,
      height: newViewBox.height
    }
  }

  SetZoomViewBox(data);
}

setup();
```

```html
<div onclick="zoomin()" style="display: block;float: left;border: 1px solid;cursor: pointer">
  ZoomIn
</div>
<div onclick="zoomout()" style="display: block;float: left;border: 1px solid;cursor: pointer;margin-left: 10px">
  ZoomOut
</div>
<svg id="mainsvg" width="600px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 600 500">
  <g id="gnode">
    <rect id="boundry" x="0" y="0" width="599" height="499" fill="none" stroke='black'/>
    <circle id="centernode" cx="300" cy="250" r="5" fill="red" stroke="none" />
    <rect id="selected" x="450" y="100" width="50" height="50" fill="blue" stroke='none'/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code to handle zoom in and zoom out based on mouse wheel event:

```
svg.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
  if (event.deltaY < 0) {
    zoomin();
  } else if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    zoomout();
  }
});
```

Place this code after the setup function. It will handle the zoom in and zoom out events when the mouse wheel is scrolled over the svg element.